# store json data in a java script variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

First thing I am new to javascript.
What I am trying to do is to get data from a URL in json and save it in java script variable.

**What I have already done:**

```
    var json = '{"result":true,"count":1}',
    obj = JSON.parse(json);
    alert(obj.count);
```

This shows me **output : 1**

and **what I want is to get data from URL like:**

```
var json ='url';
obj = JSON.parse(json);
alert(obj.count);
```

and for the clearance I am using [this](https://daewoocab-test.herokuapp.com/api/v1/rates?token=6ab676ddd7bf00101408ea3a27fdbb8ad22e9dcdf2faafdcd2ef0efc1509d463&pickup_area=Street%201%2CF-8%2CIslamabad%2CIslamabad%20Capital%20Territory%2CPakistan&drop_area=padhrarazadari.com%2C%20kallar%20kahar%20road%2C%20padhrar%2C%20punjab%2C%20pakistan&distance=169) URL to get JSON data and i just need to print **fare** from the data.

any help in this matter would be highly appreciated !!

I have done this in php like this way, but I need it to do this in javascript.

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("url");
$json = json_decode($jsonData,true);
echo $json['fare'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D%27WRC%27&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback', function(data) {
   console.log(data)
});
```

Try this ways to read ur URL

Comment: not working, actually I am trying to get data from URL in a javascript function which activates on button click

Comment: function showHint() {
  var xhttp;
  
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText));
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D%27WRC%27&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback", true);
  xhttp.send();
} this way in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, convert the url to an array then

```
var json = 'data url in array',
obj = JSON.stringify(json);
alert(obj.count);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Temporary Solution:**

Here is my working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mr_7/2qfjbfwz/)

If you get `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error, add CORS extension to your browser and enable it.

hope this helps :)

Comment: your fiddle is not displaying anything

Comment: adding CORS extension does not solve the issue, only resolve the issue in 1 computer.

Comment: yes, it is solved now, but will this works on all users?

Comment: @BilalZafar using CORS extension, works on only your machine

Comment: No. Unless you force all users to install the extension and use Chrome.

Comment: ok, so its a bad solution to implement this, is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: read more about cross-domain javascript request, or use server-side call instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax call for fetching data from external sources.

On clicking it will fetch data from the url.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://daewoocab-test.herokuapp.com/api/v1/rates?token=6ab676ddd7bf00101408ea3a27fdbb8ad22e9dcdf2faafdcd2ef0efc1509d463&pickup_area=Street%201%2CF-8%2CIslamabad%2CIslamabad%20Capital%20Territory%2CPakistan&drop_area=padhrarazadari.com%2C%20kallar%20kahar%20road%2C%20padhrar%2C%20punjab%2C%20pakistan&distance=169", function(result){
            console.log(result);
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("div").append(field + " ");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: install allow control allow origin extention. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: ok good, how can all the users will able to do this? I mean this things will work on only my pc right?

Comment: That is useful when making request between different domains. For we are making request from stackoverflow to your domain. Users will be making within the same domain. So they won't have any problem.

Comment: http://moubeenfarooqkhan.com/fyp/abc.php
I have added the code on this page and same issue, it means that every user will have to install that extension ?

Comment: can you tell me the other solution if you have ?

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="showHint()">abcd</button>
<script>
function showHint() { 

var xhttp; 
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
alert(JSON.parse(xhttp.response));
}

}; 
xhttp.open("GET", "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D%27WRC%27&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback", true);
xhttp.send();

} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This one does not depend on any jquery Use it